# Redirecting out of modal box in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

i have this component in joomla that contains a form,this form is in the modal sbox...when the form is submitted it redirects the user to the successfull message page but it is again in the modal box,my problem is that i want it to redirect to a normal page not in modal...how can i do that?

this is the redirect code from my component...

```
$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jxtcappbook'.(JRequest::getInt( 'pop', 0) ? '&view=complete&tmpl=component' : ''));
    $this->setRedirect($url,JText::_( 'You appointment was booked succesfully.'.$pop ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user the below code if you are using Joomla 2.5

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect('index.php');

and if you are using the Joomla1.5 than

global $mainframe;
$mainframe->redirect('index.php');

vote me if you really helpful to you

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used this code and i got it working,but now i need when the window closes to show a message that the submitting is succesfull...

```
function closeme()
            {

            parent.SqueezeBox.close();

            }

            window.setTimeout('closeme();',0);
```